# How can I hide sensitive information like passwords from python program output logs?

Tags: python, security, logging

I wonder if there is a python module that I can use as a filter for stdout for preventing to display sensitive information like passwords or credentials?

I am looking for a generic solution as I have no control or prior knowledge of what is effectively printed (is output of user defined shell commands). Still, as a safety measure I would prefer to hide information that is likely to be sensistive.

Real life example: "set" prints environment variable and would clearly expose `OS_PASSWORD` if defined. If the filter I am describing would just replace the value with `*` it would make it safe to use.

I tried to search on https://pypi.org but I wasnt able to find anything, yet.

We can assume that python logging is used for output as that is the recommanded way to log anything in python.

Clarification: there is no way for me to know which environment variables may need to be sanitized, by default the tool does not need any credentials so I need a generic solution that has a default set of known to be sensitiv.

The same kind of problem is faced on any CI system that is public that that needs some credentials in order to function. A decent approach is to sanitize the output to avoid accidental leakage of information. For example an user may add a "set" that would expose some of these variables to the logs.

This is not about malicious usses that may easily find a way to bypass a filtering system if they really want, is more about preventing accidental leakage caused by code that you cannot control.

So unsafe code needs access to sensitive information and you cannot prevent it from displaying it. All I am looking for is for some "white-paste" solution....

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If *you*, the developer, have `"no .. prior knowledge of what is effectively printed"` than how would a theoretically-existing module know? How would it know that `super_sensitive_password` is going to be logged?

Comment: This sounds like a symptom of a deeper problem. If you're passing credentials on the command line, be aware that on most Linux systems, *any* user on the box, even unprivileged users, can easily see the complete command line of *every* command executed. Additionally, the `root` user (or any user with unlimited `sudo` privileges) can easily inspect the environment variables of any process. Before trying to mitigate a threat, you need to understand what the threat is that you're trying to defend against.

Comment: You have two ways to solve this problem. Either (1) figure out a way to ensure that credentials are never put into logs, or (2) assume all logs contain credentials, and lock them down so only administrators are allowed to read them. Most likely, you will want to do both.

Answer (score 1):

Try hashing it by using the sha-256 algorithm